# Android EditText in ConstraintLayout is scrollable, because of 0dp height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-constraintlayout

I have an EditText inside a ConstraintLayout:

```xml
<ConstraintLayout>
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:hint="Test"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</ConstraintLayout>
```

This EditText has the full height of the screen, but I am able to scroll the hint out of the visible area.
I think it's because the height is `0dp` and the EditText somehow does not measure its actual height.

Is there any way to fix this?

**Edit:**
The whole layout file:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        style="@style/HeaderText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_feedback"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSummary"
        style="@style/ContentText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spaceXXL"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spaceXXL"
        android:text="@string/feedback_summary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edEmail"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spaceXXL"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblSummary" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edMessage"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spaceXXL"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spaceXXL"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spaceXXL"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/your_message"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnSend"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edEmail" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        style="@style/Button.Black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spaceXXL"
        android:text="@string/btn_send_feedback"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try android:layout_weight=1

Comment: plz attach whole xml file

Comment: `android:layout_weight="1"` does not work, neither does `app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"`.

Comment: Can you please share complete .xml file? Or draw the image you are trying to make

Comment: I have added the complete xml file. I cannot use `match_parent`, because I don't want the EditText to have the full height.

Answer (score 0):

In your `EditText` you can use

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="20dp"
```

Also, check your `layout_constraint` you can replace them by

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

I think this will help.

Comment: Nope, I cannot use `wrap_content` as height, because I want the ConstraintLayout to define the height of the EditText.

Comment: Can you share your XML file ? We can easily understand your problem and help you